# Why are my footnotes listed as 1. instead of ¹?

Tags: footnotes, superscripts

[image: footnotes listed wrong]

I am simply using \footnote but it seems that the layout is messed up. I use the following packages.

It should be noted that the footnote is being inserted in text, in a subfile.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%LANGUAGE
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%MATH
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{icomma}

%TABLES
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{biblatex}

%FIGURES
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

%MISC
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
% Force all footnotes to bottom
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

%APPENDIX
%\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

%BIBLIOGRAPHY
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[authordate-trad]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%SUBFILES ENVIRONMENT
%\usepackage{subfiles}
%\graphicspath{{graphs/}{../graphs/}} %Locates images for both subfiles and main file

% NEW COMMANDS
\newcommand{\paravar}[1]{\medskip \noindent \textsf{\textbf{#1}}\ }
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%bibliography
\usepackage[authordate-trad
            ]{biblatex-chicago} %alternative options are 'notes' or 'authordate'
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%Subfiles environment
\usepackage{subfiles}
\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}} %Locates images for both subfiles and main file
```

---

@leandriss

I am using the following preamble in the master-document

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
```

and

```
\documentclass[../Master.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\section{Example of section}
```

in the subsection.
Thanks

Comment: With the information you provided so far, the issue is not reproducible. Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to recreate the output you get.

Comment: Also clean up your preamble in order to avoid loading package more than once. Especially, avoid loading packages more than once and with different/conflicting package options.

Comment: Cause: The formatting of footnotes is a function of the document class. Solution: Use a different document class.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps surprisingly the package `biblatex-chicago` changes the layout of your footnotes. You can verify this in the following MWE

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

% (un)comment to see the effect
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{document}
Lorem\footnote{ipsum}
dolor\footnote{sit}
\end{document}
```

[image: Footnote "1. ipsum" no superscript.]

`biblatex-chicago` modifies the layout of the footnotes to make them conform to CMoS requirements. You can stop it from doing that with the option `footmarkoff`.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[footmarkoff]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{document}
Lorem\footnote{ipsum}
dolor\footnote{sit}
\end{document}
```

[image: Footnote "1ipsum" with "1" in superscript and almost no space between "1" and "ipsum".]

---

Unrelated to this, you may want to consider cleaning up your preamble.

You are loading a *lot* of packages which you may not all need. You are also loading several packages multiple times, which is confusing and unnecessarily bloats your preamble at best and can lead to option clash errors at worst: Load packages only once.

The preamble comments are also not fully accurate. `\usepackage{bm}` is not a tables package.

Apart from a few documented exceptions `\usepackage{hyperref}` should usually be the last package to be loaded.